# cmake + clang_tidy - disable checking in directory

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I have large project using CMake. I want to add `clang_tidy-8` support with following code:

```
set(BORG_CLANG_TIDY OFF CACHE STRING "If enabled, clang-tidy will be used. If set to 'fix', fixes will be done on source")
set_property(CACHE BORG_CLANG_TIDY PROPERTY STRINGS ON OFF fix)
if(BORG_CLANG_TIDY)
    if (BORG_CLANG_TIDY STREQUAL "fix")
        set(maybe_fix -fix)
    endif()

    set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy-8 -extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option -format-style=file ${maybe_fix} )
endif()
```

I put proper `.clang-tidy` in root directory of project (proper = with desired checks). However, there are directories that I don't want clang tidy to check/fix (3rdparty and legacy code that can't be modified because it is brittle). So I tried putting empty `.clang-tidy` file in those directories (empty = with `-checks=-*`). This doesn't work because `Error: no checks enabled.`

I hoped to find some some fake `-checks=-*,hello-world-do-nothing-check` but nothing presented itself.

Is there other way to disable checks in selected subdirectories (/subtrees)? Those directories are static and may be hardcoded in CMake if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a dummy check that would do nothing there's at least one that's pretty easy to disable by its options: [misc-definitions-in-headers](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/misc-definitions-in-headers.html)

The `HeaderFileExtensions` option can be used to make the check work with only certain header file suffixes. If you set it to something non-existent line "x" then you have a `hello-world-do-nothing-check` alternative. Your clang-tidy file would then look something like this:

```
Checks: '-*,misc-definitions-in-headers'
CheckOptions:
  - { key: HeaderFileExtensions,          value: "x" }
```

You can also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319752/9874699 and try to adapt the `line-filter` to filter out files from certain directories.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there other way to disable checks in selected subdirectories (/subtrees)?

In CMakeList.txt files contained in those subdirectories, add the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
```

But this is not a good solution: it creates a binding between the build system and a toolchain-specific tool. `CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY` should only ever be set via the configuration command (or possibly via a tool-chain file).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used in this scenario:

```
# Disable most checks as this is third-party code
# Have to enable at least one check, so pick a benign one!
#InheritParentConfig: false
Checks:              cppcoreguidelines-avoid-goto
```

I think we can all agree "Go To Statement Considered Harmful".

Comment: Please explain your codeblock (what it does, how it solves the problem), and source claims such as `Go To Statement Considered Harmful`.

Comment: As the comment says, clang-tidy needs at least one check enabled, so I chose the goto check as one very unlikely to trigger false positive. Modern code should almost never use goto.

As to the "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" - that is one of the most famous statements in computer science.  You can google it.